# /Volumes/external_drive folder not being removed

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mount

I have a 2TB external HDD, formatted using exFAT. It seems that, even after I eject the disk, the mount point remains in `/Volumes`. Thus, every time I plug the drive in, a new mount point gets created in `/Volumes` using a numerical incrementer:

- `/Volumes/external_drive/`
- `/Volumes/external_drive 1/`
- `/Volumes/external_drive 2/`
- etc.

This is a pain, as I have my torrents written to that disk. If I have to interrupt a torrent download and unplug the drive, when I plug the drive back in, the download folder ends up in a different place which causes problems for e.g., uTorrent. This can be avoided if I remember to go in and manually delete the orphaned mount point directory, but filesystem cleanup seems to be something that the OS handles. Is there a way to avoid this?

Note for clarity: I am ejecting the disk (e.g., right-click on the desktop icon and select "Eject external_drive"). I am NOT just yanking out the USB cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been described on the ntfs-3g github page. It appears to be related to OSXFUSE:
https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/119.

There are a couple suggested remedies, including removing OSXFUSE, and using an older unsupported program with similar functionality, or else downloading and compiling OSXFUSE from the source (apparently the bug was fixed, but has not been released as of December when the thread was last updated).

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely that some program (probably uTorrent) is configured to access /Volumes/external_drive/. When the disk is ejected, that folder is deleted, but the program is re-creating it (because that's its configured location to store files), thus triggering the problem.

The only solution I know of is to make sure the program (again, probably uTorrent) *never* runs when the disk is not mounted. Quit the program (and if it has any background processes, shut them down), *then* eject the disk. And don't restart the program until after you've remounted the disk.

Comment: Not a bad hypothesis, though I just launched uTorrent with the /Volumes directory already cleared out of orphaned mount points (I can't remember whether I removed /Volumes/external_drive/ manually) and with the drive not attached, this did not trigger the creation of the mount point.

Comment: Is there anything else that might be configured to use /Volumes/external_drive (possibly via an alias)? BTW, you can watch for activity with `sudo fs_usage | grep /Volumes/external_drive`, and see what programs are accessing that path.

Comment: Apparently fs_usage doesn't report directory creation, so that won't work. Try `sudo dtrace -Fn 'syscall::mkdir:entry { printf("\nmkdir path: %s exename: %s\n", copyinstr(arg0), execname); }' | grep external_drive` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've never used dtrace before, so I'm not really sure what to make of it, but after trying your suggestion, I get: `dtrace: description 'syscall::mkdir:entry ' matched 1 probe`.

Comment: Just now I wonder if the culprit is OSXFUSE.